# How to shorten a macro for conditional "0" prefixing

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I would like to do this:

```
#if ID1 < 10
#define ID1_STR  "0" #ID1
#else
#define ID1_STR  #ID1
#endif
```

But, I don't want to repeat this for every "ID".  Is there a way I can create some wrapper, where I can just do this:

```
WRAPPER(ID1)
```

Comment: Why? Bang head a few times. Why?

Comment: You're probably better off with a bunch of copy-pasting (maybe using an editor macro!)

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done with the preprocessor, since it is not possible for a macro to expand to a set of preprocessor directives (#if, #define, etc).   And that's what would be needed to do what you seek.